# SSH public/private keys work in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a server that supports SSH Key-Auth login. I've made my key-pairs, uploaded them... etc. In short, it works--in Windows. I made the key-pair using Putty's key maker (PuttyGen IIRC) on my Windows XP box, however on my Linux box I can't "unlock" the key.

- Permissions are set to 700 on the key file.
- The password is correct, I'm 100% sure of it.
- I'm running the command "`ssh -i mykey.ppk myuser@myhost.com`" with obvious substitutions made.
- The key is in my `~/.ssh` directory.
- The error is "`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).`"

The only thing I can think of is that it must be something between Linux and Windows. I've tried e-mailing myself the key file, directly copying it from my other HDD to this one, having another person email it to me from their Linux installation... it just won't work. This is the -only- thing preventing me from using Linux full-time for coding (something I really want to do!) so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The PUBLIC key is on the server, right?

Comment: And what do you mean by "it works in Windows"? Your Windows machine is the client, right? So, Windows is only half of the client-server combination?

Comment: Or: are you trying to use both Linux and Windows as the client? (In which case indeed the private key must be on both Windows and Linux.)

Comment: I'm using both Linux and Windows as clients, I have dual-boot setup on my computer at home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `puttygen` on the Windows machine to convert the private key to openssh format.

```
puttygen putty-key.ppk -O private-openssh -o ssh-key.pem
```

[[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20110730045557/http://leadingedgescripts.co.uk/server-administration/how-to-convert-your-putty-ppk-private-key-to-a-normal-ssh-key-you-can-use-on-an-apple-mac/)]

Comment: Who knew it would be so easy? Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY uses its own format. You will need to convert that, or [start the other way around](http://linux-sxs.org/networking/openssh.putty.html).

Comment: I've tried using the Linux version of Putty, though, with the same result.

Comment: Converting seems like it might work, though. I'd like to give that a try--where should I look?

Comment: See http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-savepub -- it might be easier to create a new key pair, so scroll up a bit then.

Comment: Assuming both Windows and Linux are clients, then generating a new key pair also needs work on the server. Not needed; see http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-conversions then.